# How to prevent reloading single page application after clicking navigation bar items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a simple SPA (it contains carousel part, about us part, some forms, then team part...) and I have an easy question: how to prevent reloading page after clicking navigation bar items and keep url same as on the beginning? On click on every navbar item page scrolls down to selected part.

This is my code:

**HTML navigation bar:**

```
<nav id="navBar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigationBar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toogle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="./media/img/....png"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigationBar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#abc">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#aaa">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#bbb">...</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registrationModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Registration</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</nav>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.navbar li a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function (){
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top - 100
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If i'm understanding this correctly, you just need to add a prevent default for the a tag

```
$('.navbar li a').click(function (event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 100},2000);
});
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

1.)
`event.preventDefault()`

[Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) about it.

Prevents the `<a>` from reloading.

```
$('.navbar li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 100
    },2000);
});
```

2.) `href`with a hash

If you change the `<a href="#">` it will not reload the page, because the link refers to an internal change. However, this is unfavorable due to the nature of single page applications.

Comment: And is there a way to make a url prettier?

Comment: Define prettier? I usually use the www.example.com/#/page/ syntax.

Comment: I updated jQuery code. Can you please explain it to me because I found it on internet and it does exactly what I need?

Comment: It's a bit complicated / obfuscated. check the documentation on `window.location.hash` to see what I mean.